# ASP.NET5.0 Add html file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I got a html file index.html that i want to link with my asp.net5 project.

I have tried to add the index.html in wwwroot and when I start the debug I go to localhost:port/index.html and it shows me nothing.

Can some one link to a documentation or explain how to do it?

PS: I use visual-studio.

Config code:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the app that you want to use static files. You wouldn't need it in a Web Api 2.0 server for instance. So, this is not added by default. In your Startup.cs add app.UseStaticFiles(); to the Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{    
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for response but i dont get use static files i only get app.UseIISPlatformHandler and app.UseMiddleware

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",

Comment: add the dependencies in your project.json